# Prove that $\alpha^n<\sum_{k=1}^n {2n \choose n+k}k^2<\beta^n$, when $0<\alpha<4<\beta$ are constants

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

> Let $\alpha,\beta$ constants such that $0<\alpha<4<\beta$. Prove that $\exists n_0.\forall n>n_0$ $$\alpha^n<\sum_{k=1}^n {2n \choose n+k}k^2<\beta^n$$

**My attempt:**

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n {2n \choose n+k}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(2n)!}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot (n-1)n}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(n+k)}\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot (n-1)n}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(n+k)}\cdot{2n \choose n}k^2$$
> Using the Stirling Approximation we get
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\frac{(n-k+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot (n-1)n}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(n+k)}\cdot(1+o(1))4^n\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi n}}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\frac{(n-k+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot (n-1)n}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(n+k)}\cdot\Theta(\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}})$$

Will this get me anywhere? Or is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: Can be useful $$\sum _{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{2 n}{k+n}=4^{n-1} n$$

Comment: Could you please explain why it is correct?

Comment: I kept it as a comment because I just used this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%5E2+binomial%282n%2Ck%2Bn%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}k^2
&=\frac12\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\binom{2n}{n+k}k^2
\\&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(k-n)^2
\\&=\frac18\left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}e^{2(k-n)x}\right|_{x=0}
\\&=\frac18\left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^x+e^{-x})^{2n}\right|_{x=0}
\\&=2^{2n-3}\left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\cosh^{2n}x\right|_{x=0}
\\&=2^{2n-2}n\big((2n-1)\cosh^{2n-2}x\sinh^2 x+\cosh^{2n}x\big)_{x=0}
\\&=4^{n-1}n.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 You can also note that $ 2^{-2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}(k-n)^2 = n/2 $ because it's the variance of a $(2n, 1/2)$ binomial distribution.